# How do i merge 2 web forms into 1?

Tags: forms

I need to merge these 2 forms into 1 so it passes the email address to all 3 sources.

Is it possible?

Form 1:

```
<form method="post" id="transparent_redirect_form" name="transparent_redirect_form" action="https://joinalpha.com/launch/signup.php/taster">
<input type="text" id="signup_email_address" name="signup_email_address" placeholder="you@business.com" />
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form method="post" action="http://joinalpha.com/blog/signup/"><input type="hidden" name="ip" value="213.106.180.209" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="s2email" value="you@business.com" onfocus="if (this.value == 'you@business.com') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'you@business.com';}" />
<input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Each form has only one field and one action - to send the email address somewhere...

Any clues how i do this?

Comment: so simply you want to perform 3 different actions on click of submit ?

Comment: Well 2, i edited it down to make it easier. but yes...

Comment: If you want to do several POST actions in response to a user submission, it might be best to do everything in one form, sent it to your server, and do the submissions from your server. Is `joinalpha.com` your own website, or a third party?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use javascript.

Create a button or something outside of the form, then invoke the submit of the form, then use the DOM to change the action in the form, and call submit again.